# How exactly do shadows work in The Chronicles of Amber?

Tags: roger-zelazny, chronicles-of-amber

I’m still reading the first book and what I don’t understand is how the shadows are created. Do they work like parallel universes, or are all of them created by the princes of Amber trying to get to a certain place, thus creating some number of permutations along the way?

Comment: Even in the books they don't know; they speculate, and there is a common debate as to if they simply find what they are looking for in a Multiverse of possibilities, or, if by looking, they are creating them.  From a practical perspective, it doesn't matter, so they wonder, but don't really have any answers.  Merlin creates a tool to index shadows, but the same question exists -- what exactly is it indexing -- all possibilities, or all possibilities that one of them has explored.

Comment: I see so I should just read on and not wait for a hard answer . thank you .

Comment: "Do we make the Shadow worlds? Or are they there, independent of us, awaiting our footfalls? Or is there an unfairly excluded middle? Is it a matter of more or less, rather than either-or? A dry chuckle arose suddenly as I realized that I might never know the answer for certain. Yet,"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shadows are cast by the Pattern (emphasis mine):

> ...but of Shadow I have this to say: there is Shadow and there is
>   Substance, and this is the root of all things.  Of Substance, there is
>   only Amber, the real city, upon the real Earth, which contains
>   everything.  Of Shadow, there is an infinitude of things.  Every
>   possibility exists somewhere as a Shadow of the real.  **Amber, by its
>   very existence, has cast such in all directions.**  And what may one
>   say of it beyond?  Shadow extends from Amber to Chaos, and all things
>   are possible within it.

(Page 77, *The Chronicles of Amber*)

Corwin says that "in a sense" the shadow walkers create them, but personally I think this is him being poetic rather than literal, given the cite above (and given Corwin's penchant for waxing poetical):

> You may call them parallel worlds if you wish, alternate universes if
>   you would, the products of a deranged mind if you care to.  I call
>   them shadows, as do all who possess the power to walk among them.  We
>   select a possibility and we walk until we reach it.  **So, in a sense,
>   we create it.  Let's leave it at that for now.**

(Page 123, *The Chronicles of Amber*)

I think that "parallel universes cast by the pattern" is the truest answer, given:

> what we learn about Corwin's pattern, the disruptions to reality it causes,
>  and the null space between patternverses throughout Merlin's books.  The role
>  of the pattern(s) in being basic to reality as a foil to chaos supports the
>  stance that the patterns are what "create" the multiple realities called Shadows.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I think you are underestimating Zelazny's love of ambiguity. He was deliberate in his ineffability.

Comment: From later on in Merlin books we also learn to think of Shadows differently,taking into account Chaos. But I don't want to spoil it.